# How to show specific numbers of items in the gridview to different screen size on Windows 8 .net Metro Style app?

Tags: .net, windows, xaml, windows-8

How to show specific numbers of items in the gridview to different screen size on Windows 8 .net Metro Style app?

I've tried to use the VariableSize Wrapgrid "MaximumRowsorColumns" but that only limit the row of the grid view item, I've seen some app that, when there are 2 rows, they show 4 items per group - when there are 3 rows (because of the bigger screen.), they show 8 items per group.
But those are .JS Apps.

Is it possible to show the numbers of item according to the row that it is currently showing on the screen?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

The Metro Framework should automatically resize your items on different screen size. That is, if you designed your UI as fluent. If it is static then no matter what your size screen is it will always look like that. If you notice if you have smaller screen size you only get up to 3 rows on the GridViewItem of the Startup Screen but if it has a bigger screen size (resolution) it takes up to 4 row.

To answer your question: Yes it is possible.